# How can I create given query In SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to create this query in SQL Server 2012 to add a column

In MySQL I use:

```
ALTER TABLE employee 
  ADD COLUMN field BOOLEAN NOT NULL;
```

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: tnx @Marc_s but Plz don't give negative vote

Comment: I **DID NOT** downvote your question ..... I only cleaned it up a bit to make it easier to read and understand

Comment: ok tnx marc..can you vote my question?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things wrong here

1. SQL Server does not have a boolean type - try bit type
2. SQL Server insists on a default value if you specify not null

Try

```
ALTER TABLE employee 
    ADD BitFIELD BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```